# Lazily initialising static variables in a multi-threaded situation

Tags: java, synchronized, volatile, static-variables

I am trying to write an instance method to lazily initialise several static variables. The objects I am initialising are immutable, and the references for the objects are not changed by any other instance or static methods in the class. I want the initialization code to never be executed more than once even though there may be several instances of the class in many different threads. The initialization needs to take place in an instance method as the method overrides a method in a superclass. My approach I am using is as follows.

```
private static volatile boolean isPrepared;
private static volatile Object object1;
private static volatile Object object2;
private static volatile Object object3;

@Override
void prepare() {
    synchronized (this.getClass()) {
        if (isPrepared) { return; }
        object1 = expensiveCalculation1();
        object2 = expensiveCalculation2();
        object3 = expensiveCalculation3();
        isPrepared = true;
    }   
}
```

I am assuming that since the initialization takes place in a single synchronized block, it would be impossible for an instance to ever observe `isPrepared` as being `true` unless `object1`, `object2` and `object3` are all non-null. I am also assuming that it wouldn't work by simply declaring `prepare()` as `synchronized` as the lock would just be `this`. Are my assumptions right? Also, is it a good idea to have several variables marked `volatile` when you want to regard them as being initialised together, or should I bundle them together into a single Immutable class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling all lazily-initialized state into an immutable object is usually the preferred approach because then *all* you need is a `volatile` variable, with no synchronization. That arrangement opens you to some duplicated effort if another thread starts initializing while initialization is in progress, but the chances of that can be minimized, such as by writing a sentinel value to the `volatile` to signal the "in progress" state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will use the approach of bundling the variables into a single volatile variable. However, isn't the combination of volatile and a synchronized block the simplest way to completely eliminate the possibility of the duplication you mention?

Comment: Yes, it is. First check the volatile var for a value, then enter the synchronized block if needed.

Comment: Good point. You wouldn't want to wait for other threads if the var is already there. Would you have to check the volatile var for a value twice, once to see if the synchronized block is needed, and once at the beginning of the block? Since the initial check is not synchronized, the initialisation could have completed in another thread by the time you enter the synchronized block.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how the proper double-checked idiom looks in Java. Check this interview with Josh Bloch to see both this idiom and another, which offers even more convenience (holder class). http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use next approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879164/2413618
Put your variables into static nested class. When nested class will be accessed first time then all variables will be initialized.